# $n$ amount of lines make $m$ amount of intersection points. How many values of $m$?

Tags: plane-geometry

What I am asking is this. Given $n$ amount of lines, there are $m$ amount of intersection points. How many values of $m$ are there? Let me give an example, 5 lines in a plane. Is there a formula for this, and if so, proof?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlaneDivisionbyLines.html

Comment: @EricTowers I'm not looking for the division of planes, I'm looking for intersection points

Comment: See solution 2 at : https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/LinesDividePlane.shtml